# need help : how to handling for "clear data"

Tags: java, android

i build application android....and i want to back up my database when user click "clear data" in manage application...because data is lost...some data is very critical for process in my application...how can i solved this???
please help me .....

thanks...

Comment: if you could backup then i don't think there is any meaning left for the word 'Clear Data', consider creating your own version of android

Comment: better save your database on external storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to back up my database when user click "clear data"

You can't override the desire of the user to delete data. Maybe he just does not use your app and needs space.

When your app starts after that it behaves like it was just freshly installed from the market. That is how it is intended and you should not try to work around that.

Comment: In the application, I created outbox stored in sqlite. how to backup the outbox when user click "clear data". outbox is very important and should not be lost. maybe you have a suggestion for me to outbox can be backed up, when or before the user click "clear data"?
thanks

Comment: Your app does not get any notification about data being deleted so it has no chance to save data, that's the intention of clear data. Either instruct users that clearing data will delete the data so they don't do it or add a backup/restore functionality that the user can initiate and store a copy of the data on external storage then. Or move your data entirely to external storage since that is not deleted. But that would expose the data complete to the user and he could delete / modify it in even more ways.